# Asp.net Identity 2 The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have 3 projects in my solution, Domain, API and Web. Recently I've updated Asp.net Identity form 1.0 to 2.0. And everything works fine in my Web project but when I try to get Token in Web API project I get this error (an before upgrading Identity from 1.0 to 2.0 everything worked):

```
The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context
```

My User class looks like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
   //more code here
}
```

Here is My Database context class:

```
    public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
        {
            public DatabaseContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
                Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            }

          //more code here

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        }

    }
```

In my Web API project I've replaced all references from IdentityUser to User, for example method for getting Token looks like:

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (UserManager<User> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
        {
            var user =   userManager.Find(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I think IdentityDbContext creates a DbSet for the given User type so I'm not sure if this is right - but try `modelBuilder.Entity<User>()...` instead of `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()...`

Comment: I have both, but I deleted modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>() and left just modelBuilder.Entity<User>(), but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it,

So the problem was with updating Asp.net Identity from 1.0 to 2.0 as ASP.net Web API handles things bit differently for 2.0 so what I did was:

1. Updated VS 2013 (Update 2)
2. Created new Web API 2 project in another solution, and compared it with my Web API project
   And added missing classes to it (just copy/paste)
3. To my DatabaseContext class I've added method:

   public static DatabaseContext Create()
           {
               return new DatabaseContext();
           }
4. And to my User class:

   public async Task GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager manager, string authenticationType)
       {
           // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
           // Add custom user claims here
           return userIdentity;
       }
5. And I've changed all ApplicationUser references in Web API project with my User   reference